# MATLAB How to include variables in input, in for loops?

Tags: matlab, variables, input

So the code goes something like this..

```
for i=1:5
x(i) = input(['Input for number', i );
end
```

when i run, instead i get something like "Input a complex number []" where [] is just a block (i cannot get the symbol here), how do i make it so for every input it can say "Input for number 1", "Input for number 2", etc?

Answer (score 3):

When casting from double to char, you convert between ASCII-Codes and the character. To get the character `1` use `num2str`

```
for i=1:5
  x(i) = input(['Input for number ', num2str(i)]);
end
```

Comment: @JitheshSrinivas Rather than a "thank you" comment, which is not really what the comments are for, it would be better to accept the answer that you think best by clicking the check (tick) mark to the left. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.